# Change & save SPAN CSS on AJAX SUCCESS then retrieve saved information

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I've got the following code that works with AJAX, PHP, PDO , HTML and CSS. It's functionality is rating button that sends to database on AJAX post by either adding a +1 to MySQL
or taking -1 from it, just a normal rating system like facebook's "like".

The current situationg stands as follows: Once I press the ( +0 ) button, it'll call the ajax and update it to ( +1 ) in which case, the background is changed from the normal white color
to a blue background color that was added by a toggleClass on the AJAX FORM. The issue that I'm having is that, only the background is saving once I refresh the page, and plus and rateCount returns to it's
normal color. All I'm trying to do is once I press the button that currently stands at +0 with a dark font color, I'd like for it to swicth to a white color and once I refresh the page
I want it to stay there. Here is how I'm doing this with the help of a few SO users.

**note: $voterate returns the total count of likes from MySQL.**

---

```
.up { -moz-user-select: none; background-color: #FFFFFF; background-image: none; border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); cursor: pointer; float: left; height: 28px; line-height: 26px; margin-left: 10px; outline: medium none; padding: 0 10px; transition: background-color 0.218s ease 0s, border-color 0.218s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.218s ease 0s; width: auto;}
.up:hover{ border-color: #BFBFBF; box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
.up.clicked { background-color: #427FED;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(center top , transparent, transparent); border: 1px solid transparent;}
.clicked:hover{ -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-top-colors: none; background-color: #4285F4; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , transparent, transparent); border-color: transparent transparent #2F69C2; border-image: none; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #2F69C2 inset;}

.plus { color: #696969; font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;}
.plus.PlusWhiteButton { color:#fff;}

.rateCount { color: #696969; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;}
.rateCount.RateCountWhiteButton { color:#fff;}
```

---

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT add_iP FROM PostsRating WHERE post_iD_fk = :post_iD AND add_iP = :ip");
    $sth->execute(array(':post_iD' => $post_iD, ':ip' => $ip));
    $clicked = ($sth->fetchColumn()) ? " clicked" : ""; // i'm confuse on how this get's the clicked class, it seems really inneficient but it works one way or another.
?> 
<span class="up vote<?php echo $clicked;?>" name="voteUp" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
    <span class="plus">+</a>
    <span class="rateCount"><?php echo $VoteRate;?></a>
</span>
```

---

```
$(function()
{
    $(".vote").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this);

        if (name=='voteUp')
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "voting/up_vote.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    parent.toggleClass("clicked"); // clicked function changes the background and is the only one that actually stays once the page is refreshed.
                    parent.find(".rateCount").html(html);
                    parent.find(".rateCount").toggleClass("RateCountWhiteButton");
                    parent.find(".plus").toggleClass("PlusWhiteButton");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And Here is how I'm adding the information from the AJAX. not sure if it's needed at all.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT add_iP FROM PostsRating WHERE post_iD_fk = :id AND add_iP = :ip");
    $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id'], ':ip' => $ip));

    if( $sth->fetchColumn() == 0)
    {
        $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts set voteUp = voteUp+1 where post_iD = :id");
        $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));

        $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT into PostsRating (post_iD_fk, add_iP) VALUES (:id, :ip)");
        $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id'], ':ip' => $ip));
    } else  {
                $sth = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts set voteUp = voteUp-1 where post_iD = :id");
                $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));

                $sth = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM PostsRating WHERE post_iD_fk = :id AND add_iP = :ip");
                $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id'], ':ip' => $ip));
            }

    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT voteUp FROM posts WHERE post_iD = :id");
    $sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));

    $row = $sth->fetch();   

    echo $row['voteUp'];
}
```

I'm not sure if I explained clearly that anyone can understand so here it is again more clearly.

**[+0]**(color:black;background:white;) standby if not clicked.

if I click on the button it turns into **[+1]**(color:white;background:blue;)

If I click the **[+1]** button to remove my rating then it turns into **[+0]**(color:black;background:white;).
The only issue is saving that if I clicked it then It'll stay white and blue background.

Comment: It looks like the PHP code for creating the page just needs to add the `PlusWhiteButton` and `RateCountWhiteButton` classes in the same way that it adds the `clicked` class.

Comment: I've tried that honestly, it did not work for some reason, I figured that the query was the issue since it wasn't pulling that information and not even saving. It just resets the colors back to black instead of saving the white.

Comment: What information is needed for those colors? Isn't it the same as the information for the background color? The click Javascript toggles them all at the same time, so what's the difference?

Comment: It toggles all correctly and the colors goes from black to white when toggled but the only issue is that when I refresh the page the colors instead of saving to white when I toggle they return back to black(their old color instead of being saved and retrieved even when I refresh)

Comment: I get that. And it's because you're not setting the correct classes in the PHP code. You do it correctly for the `up` span, but not the `plus` and `rateCount` spans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds classes to the `plus` and `rateCount` spans similarly to the way the `clicked` class is added to the `up` span.

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT add_iP FROM PostsRating WHERE post_iD_fk = :post_iD AND add_iP = :ip");
    $sth->execute(array(':post_iD' => $post_iD, ':ip' => $ip));
    $clicked = $pluswhite = $ratewhite = '';
    if ($sth->fetchColumn()) {
      $clicked = " clicked";
      $pluswhite = " PlusWhiteButton";
      $ratewhite = " RateCountWhiteButton";
?> 
<span class="up vote<?php echo $clicked;?>" name="voteUp" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
    <span class="plus<?php echo $pluswhite;?>">+</a>
    <span class="rateCount<?php echo $ratewhite;?>"><?php echo $VoteRate;?></a>
</span>
```

Comment: Sigh, I can't wait to learn quicker how to code! Would make life so much easier:/ Thank you, it's perfect. Now I understand what you did instead of that other code it was so confusing.